# I want to call parent class method which is overridden in child class through child class object in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-object, python-class

```
class abc():
    def xyz(self):
        print("Class abc")

class foo(abc):
    def xyz(self):
        print("class foo")

x = foo()
```

I want to call xyz() of the parent class, something like;

```
x.super().xyz()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With single inheritance like this it's easiest in my opinion to call the method through the class, and pass `self` explicitly:

```
abc.xyz(x)
```

Using `super` to be more generic this would become (though I cannot think of a good use case):

```
super(type(x), x).xyz()
```

Which returns a super object that can be thought of as the parent class but with the child as `self`.

If you want something exactly like your syntax, just provide a super method for your class (your `abc` class, so everyone inheriting will have it):

```
def super(self):
    return super(type(self), self)
```

and now `x.super().xyz()` will work. It will break though if you make a class inheriting from `foo`, since you will only be able to go one level up (i.e. back to `foo`).

There is no "through the object" way I know of to access hidden methods.

Just for kicks, here is a more robust version allowing chaining super calls using a dedicated class keeping tracks of `super` calls:

```
class Super:
    def __init__(self, obj, counter=0):
        self.obj = obj
        self.counter = counter

    def super(self):
        return Super(self.obj, self.counter+1)

    def __getattr__(self, att):
        return getattr(super(type(self.obj).mro()[self.counter], self.obj), att)


class abc():
    def xyz(self):
        print("Class abc", type(self))

    def super(self):
        return Super(self)


class foo(abc):
    def xyz(self):
        print("class foo")


class buzz(foo):
    def xyz(self):
        print("class buzz")


buzz().super().xyz()
buzz().super().super().xyz()
```

results in

```
class foo
Class abc
```

Comment: Yes, but my objective here is to call the method through object. There must be some way for this as well. Thank you for your fast response <3

Comment: @SyedFasih What do you mean? You want `x.super()` to work as in your example? Otherwise, no you are wrong as far as I know. `super` is the builtin method meant for this, and is not part of objects.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit what `super(type(self), self)` really means. It will be very helpful.

Comment: "Using super to be more generic" is probably not actually a good thing here. The most likely scenario is that there's a specific implementation this call site wants to call, not that the call site wants to skip any implementation present in whatever the most derived class of `x` happens to be.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I agree with you.